# How To Add Verification To Your Program

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I need help with adding verification to my program. What I essentially want to happen is when they purchase the program they get sent an activation email containing their code then when they install the program it asks for and needs to match up with the code from the email.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're asking for help designing a serial number system. You could look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/559197/1484617) for a basic method of doing it. Ultimately, it doesn't need to be complex unless your app will be very widely used.

Comment: Do you know anyway to make it send the code instantly after purchase?